# AWS Cross Account SNS Publish

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-access-policy

We have two accounts 111111111111 and 222222222222.

Requirement - Account 111111111111 will create a snapshot of a RDS on a daily basis. Once the snapshot is taken, we want account 111111111111 to publish to the SNS topic created in account 222222222222. Once Account 222222222222 receives the notification it runs a Lambda function.

I have attached the following policy to the topic created in account 222222222222

```
     "Sid":"RestoreRDSEng_topic_publish",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal":{
        "AWS":"111111111111"
     },
     "Action":"sns:Publish",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:222222222222:RestoreRDSEng",
     "Condition":{
        "StringEquals":{
           "AWS:SourceAccount":"222222222222"
        },

     }
  }
```

I am receiving the following error when account 111111111111 is trying to publish to 222222222222

***"message": "AuthorizationError: User: arn:aws:sts::************assumed-role/tf-rds_eventhandler/tf-rds_eventhandler is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:RestoreRDSEng\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 098f4647-c9ad-51fe-9bc3-17b45deef60e"***

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong in this approach?
2. Should I create a role in account 222222222222 with trusted access to 111111111111?
3. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, can your requirement be simplified to "Trigger an AWS Lambda function in Account 2 when an Amazon RDS snapshot is completed in Account 1"? If so, have you considered having Amazon RDS in Account 1 send a notification to an Amazon SNS topic in Account 1, to which an AWS Lambda function in Account 2 is a subscriber? This way, SNS in Account 1 will directly trigger the Lambda function in Account 2. See: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html)

Comment: Also, a potential use case for Amazon CloudWatch Event Buses! See: [Sending and Receiving Events Between AWS Accounts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So My question is

Comment: 1) Can't we do the way I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: How do you have an Amazon RDS snapshot being created in Account 1 send a message to Amazon SNS in Account 2? The automatic notification probably can't do that.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot publish message to a SNS topic in different account automatically?

Comment: What if I create a role and the other account assumes that role

Comment: How are you doing the publishing? What is there in Account 1 that is sending the notification to SNS in Account 2 that an Amazon RDS snapshot has completed? I don't think that the automatic RDS Event Subscription can send a notification to SNS in a different account.

Comment: Thanks John for your prompt reply. This is handled by another team. I'll check with them on Monday.

Comment: John, we are actually taking the approach from  Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SNS. Do you know how we can set up a role in the account where we have the lambda function (Account 2) so that the SNS topic from account 1 can invoke it?

Comment: You can use IAM to create the role -- just choose the type as Lambda service role. It is on [step 2.2 of that tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example-create-iam-role.html). The flow sounds exactly like I outlined in my original comment (way up the top).

Answer (score 1):

This is very doable and just requires 2 parts.

First, the SNS topic receiving messages (account 2222-2222-2222) must have a policy that permits "sns:Publish" from the other account (1111-1111-1111).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:222222222222:RestoreRDSEng"
    }
  ]
}
```

Second, whatever Role you're using in 1111-1111-1111 to do the publishing must have a Policy that permits "sns:Publish" to your desired topic. This is a case where I'm generally OK using the `*` resource but you can also restrict it to the ARN of the topic in the other account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Principal` needs to be the service or role in account 11111... that you want to take the action of publishing to the SNS topic. For example:

```
 "Principal": {
     "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
   }
```

Comment: I tried for budgets, it didn't work. get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    {
      "Sid": "lambda-access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:222222222222:RestoreRDSEng"
    }
```